# How do i copy rows from one worksheet and then delete them after it has moved?

Tags: vba, excel

How do i copy rows from one worksheet programatically using VBA and then delete them after it has moved? I don't seem to be deleting all records based on the criteria, i'm searching for.

```
Dim lRowCounter as Long, lTotalRows as Long,sCommPerUnit  as String,lExceptionRowCounter  as Long

lTotalRows = 10

For lRowCounter = 1 To lTotalRows

    'If Row has no mapping, move it to Exceptions Report
    sCommPerUnit = Trim(rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, 2))

    If (sCommPerUnit = "SOMETHING") Then

        lExceptionRowCounter = lExceptionRowCounter + 1
        'Move row to Exception Report Worksheet
        rExceptionRange.Offset(lExceptionRowCounter, 1) = Trim(rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, Output_Order))

        'Delete Row from Report
        rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next
```

regards

Kojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting rows in a range, it's almost always better to start with the last row and work backwards. This means that deleting a row doesn't change anything about the rows you have yet to look at

```
Dim lRowCounter as Long, lTotalRows as Long,sCommPerUnit  as String,lExceptionRowCounter  as Long

lTotalRows = 10

For lRowCounter = lTotalRows To 1 Step -1

    'If Row has no mapping, move it to Exceptions Report
    sCommPerUnit = Trim(rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, 2))

    If (sCommPerUnit = "SOMETHING") Then

        lExceptionRowCounter = lExceptionRowCounter + 1
        'Move row to Exception Report Worksheet
        rExceptionRange.Offset(lExceptionRowCounter, 1) = Trim(rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, Output_Order))

        'Delete Row from Report
        rRange.Offset(lRowCounter, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next lRowCounter
```

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting the first row then shifting up, but incrementing to the next row. Meaning, you are skipping row. I would always delete the first row and shift up. Then on the next loop, the next row will be the first row again.

```
    'If Row has no mapping, move it to Exceptions Report 
    sCommPerUnit = Trim(rRange.Offset(0, 2)) 

    ...

    'Move FIRST row to Exception Report Worksheet'S LAST ROW
    rExceptionRange.Offset(lExceptionRowCounter, 1) = Trim(rRange.Offset(0, Output_Order)) 

    'Delete FIRST Row from Report 
    rRange.Offset(0, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
```